# Make GCM notification open app without setting click_action

Tags: android, ios, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

Okay, so I know at first glance it seems like I'm stupid because I can just set the "click_action" parameter in the notification JSON from the server and have it open the activity with the matching intent filter. However, I don't want to do this, because as the documentation goes on to say "If set, [click_action] corresponds to category in APNS payload," and setting it makes the notifications not be delivered on my iOS app (because there is no corresponding category on the iOS app nor do I want to make one as that requires, I believe, adding in notification actions which I don't want to get involved in yet).

On iOS tapping the notification just opens the equivalent of the Android "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" action. Bottom line, is there any way to replicate this in Android (or solve the iOS not displaying notifications if the "click_action" is set)?

Answer (score 0):

In GCM intent class, on Message receive method just parse all the content and then simply start activity by putting inside intent, which activity you want to open on msg received.

Comment: If the app is running the background and receives a notification, it doesn't get sent to the "onMessageRecieve" method until the app is opened which also doesn't really help. :/

Comment: That's not right, once you registered you device, and that app is installed, its always run a thread for accepting push whether is in Background or in foregroung and when got a push, onMessageRecieved()  always fired. In an app, i have a requirement of opening the app, once got a push, so in onMessageReceived(), i just parse json response and opening an intent to open app with that specific activity.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using different payloads for Android and iOS clients. This would require your clients to identify their platform when they submit their InstanceID tokens, but once you know what platform the client is you can formulate the message more specific to the target platform.

Comment: Doesn't that defeat the entire purpose of using GCM for both? At that point I may as well use GCM/APNs for each one.